# MVC3 UrlHelperExtensions with Razor Views (from .ASPX)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, image, src

I looked through everything I could find on Razor Views, but I could not find anything on how to convert this UrlHelper usage to Razor from WebForms.

**.ASPX Code Sample:**

```
<img src="<%= Url.AccountPicture(Model.Picture, "bigger") %>" alt="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Model.FullName) %>" width="73" height="73" />
```

**How I converted it to RAZOR:**

```
<img src="@Url.AccountPicture(Model.Picture, "bigger")" alt="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.FullName)" width="73" height="73" />
```

**The UrlHelperExtensions.cs File that goes with it:**

```
namespace ShadowVenue.Extensions
    {
        public static class UrlHelperExtensions
        {
            public static string AccountPicture(this UrlHelper helper, string name, string size)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                    name = "default";

                return helper.Content(string.Format("~/content/images/pictures/{0}_{1}.png", name, size));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error That Visual Studio Highlights |@Url.*AccountPicture*| with:**

*'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'AccountPicture' and no extension method 'AccountPicture' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.Helper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)*

**It Produces This Error on RunTime:**

*'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'AccountPicture' and no extension method 'AccountPicture' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I have namespace ShadowVenue.Extensions registed in the web.config

Please Help, Thank You!

Comment: Would anyone know the awnser to this question also? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975354/html-beginform-displaying-system-web-mvc-html-mvcform-on-page

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `ShadowVenue.Extensions` namespace in the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` tag (not the `<pages>` tag).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to SLaks' answer, you could put a `@using ShadowVenue.Extensions` tag at the top of your razor view for a one-off reference.

Comment: I went ahead and used this method, and it worked out great, thank you very much!