# @Html.BeginForm Displaying "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm" on Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.beginform

I have a razor view that I added a delete button to inside of an 'if' statement and when the view is rendered in the browser it is displaying **"System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm"** next to the delete button.

How do I get rid of it?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="deletestatusupdate">
    @if (update.User.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        @Html.BeginForm("deleteupdate", "home")
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.ToString())
        <button name="id" value="@update.StatusUpdateId">Delete</button>
    }
</div>
```

**Here is how it shows up in the rendered Razor View:**

*System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm* **[Delete Button]**

pretend that [delete button] is a an actual button, didn't feel like taking a screen shot.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The recommended way to generate a form is the following:

```
<div id="deletestatusupdate">
    @if (update.User.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        using(Html.BeginForm("deleteupdate", "home"))
        {
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.ToString())
            <button name="id" value="@update.StatusUpdateId">Delete</button>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
<div id="deletestatusupdate">
    @if (update.User.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Html.BeginForm("deleteupdate", "home");
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.ToString())
        <button name="id" value="@update.StatusUpdateId">Delete</button>
        Html.EndForm();
    }
</div>
```

The reason why your original approach did not work is because `BeginForm()` writes directly to the output.

Comment: using `@using(Html.BeginForm("deleteupdate", "home"))` worked for me

Answer (score 34):

Please use @using instead of using the issue will resolved I am using MVC 4

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("deleteupdate", "home"))
{
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.ToString())
    <button name="id" value="@update.StatusUpdateId">Delete</button>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Get right for this we can use them

```html
Using(Html.Beginform("Delete", "Home", new { Id = item.id } ))
{
   @* We right the code. *@
}
```