# Razor form displaying unwanted text on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have an page where I create a form like

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

@Styles.Render("~/bundles/login/css")

@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", null)
{
    // Normal HTML content that constructs the form.
}
```

The form works as expected and is redirecting to the specified controller when submitted, but the following unwanted text is displayed at the top of the page,

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm {}
```

I can't figure out why this text would be displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975354/html-beginform-displaying-system-web-mvc-html-mvcform-on-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

@Styles.Render("~/bundles/login/css")

@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", null))
{
 // Normal HTML content that constructs the form.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", null))
{
//Code here 
}
```

or Else use

`Html.EndForm` for complimenting the `Html.Beginform`