# asp.net mvc @Html.BeginForm diplays unwanted text

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application without any models. I just do not need them for what I am trying to do. I want to take some input from the view and to pass it on the controller. So far so good. The problem is that on the view I get some unwanted text: "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm"; it comes from the  follwoing line: @Html.BeginForm("GetInfo", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TestForm" } )

More precisely, my code is this:
--the view

```
    @Html.BeginForm("GetInfo", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TestForm" } )
    <br/>
    <legend>Report</legend>
    <br />
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label>Date From</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input name="dateFrom" type="date" required />
    </div>
    <br />

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

and the method from the controller is :

```
 public ActionResult GetInfo(DateTime dateFrom)
        {
//some code
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: See similar question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975354/html-beginform-displaying-system-web-mvc-html-mvcform-on-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(.....))
{
  // Html here
}
```