# Why we need to use @using with Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can someone explain to me why we need to use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Instead of :

```
@Html.BeginForm("CheckUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
```

What is the main purpose of @using in here, as far as I know, I only use 'using' keyword to make sure that the object is disposed as soon as it goes out of scope. I am a little confused.

I am asking this question because @Html.BeginForm outputs a text : "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm {" before rendering the content of the form. **And by using the 'using' keyword this text is not rendered.**

Edit: This is my code that renders the "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm ..."

```
@Html.BeginForm("CheckUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
    <label for="username">Username :</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username"/>

    <label for="password">Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
@{Html.EndForm();}
```

Comment: that is to generate corresponding closing tag (in this case the closing <form> tag)

Comment: I am not convinced yet, why we need to use the using keyword ?

Comment: The output of the closing tag is implemented by the dispose method. By not using 'using' you would not have a closing '</form>' tag.

Comment: Why without using the 'using' keyword the output is "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm { ..." ? and we also have the closing tag </form> ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Html.BeginForm Displaying "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm" on Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975354/html-beginform-displaying-system-web-mvc-html-mvcform-on-page)

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4975908/3901618

Comment: Nope, it is different, I don't want the solution, I know that using keyword is working fine, i just want to know what goes behind the scene

Comment: @Souregi, You can always inspect the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/FormExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using `@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`

It automatically adds `</form>` in your page. you don't need to care about closing your form tag and it prevents accidental issue if somebody forgets to close the form.

```
@*<form>*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CheckUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
    {

    }@* </form> gets added automaticaly*@
```

If you want to use Html.EndForm(), use it like following

```
@{Html.BeginForm("CheckUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post);}
//other form elements
@{Html.EndForm();}
```

Reason: `Html.EndForm()` doesn't returns anything( return type `void`), it write on the stream in stead. If you don't use `{}`, `@` symbol will expect something to return from the following statement hence it will use `object.ToString()` which results into `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm`

Comment: I used the @Html.EndForm but it still renders "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm " before rendering the content of the form.

Comment: use it like  this @{Html.EndForm();}

Comment: yes, i used this form actually @{Html.EndForm();}, the @Html.EndForm did not work for me :) .But it still renders "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm "

Comment: your begin form statement should also be like @{Html.BeginForm(...)}
can you paste your html along with these helpers in your question?

Comment: yeah, you have not added Begin form correctly. check the usage in my answer again and try

Answer (score 4):

`BeginForm` has a rather interesting (mis)use of the `IDisposible` pattern!

Starting at the beginning, [`BeginForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) returns an instance of [`MvcForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.mvcform(v=vs.118).aspx). `MvcForm` implements `IDisposible` and its `Dispose` method...

> [...] renders the closing  tag at the end of a Using statement.

<sub>(source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.mvcform.dispose(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm.Dispose)</sub>

Without this sort of implementation you would need to do something along the lines  of

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("CheckUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post); }
<!-- form content here -->
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

Which, I guess, they made the decision would be clunky and easy to forget.

Comment: Thanks for the @{Html.EndForm();}, this is first time I hear of about it, But it still renders "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm { ..."

Comment: @Souregi, Both the `BeginForm()` and `EndForm()` need to be wrapped in `@{ ... }` because they return `void` (Jamiec, I took the liberty of editing your answer to show the correct syntax - and `EndForm()` does exist :)

Comment: thump up for Stephen Muecke it is clear for me now :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a trick to force rendering of the close tags of the form.

The trick is based on the `IDisposable` interface, which `using` understands and uses to call the `Dispose` method after the block has ended.

The `Dispose` implementation of the type returned from `BeginForm` actually doesn't dispose anything. It just writes the closing tag to the output stream.

Comment: I agree - its just syntax sugar for knowing what the scope of your form is, in order to close it.